# Is it possible to assign set the default value of a class property based on another property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class, generics

I have this list which has `Value` property and `CharToRead`
I am trying to figure out a way to set `CharToRead`automatically to the `Value.Length`

I think this could be done through constructor but I am not even able to create a constructor since I have a generic class.

**CLASS:**

```
  public class HeaderType<T>
    {
        public string FieldTag { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

public class HeaderTypeEnq<T> : HeaderType<T>
{
    public string Mandatory { get; set; }
    public string CharacterType { get; set; }
    public string FixedLength { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public int CharToRead { get; set; }    
}
```

**LIST:**

```
  List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>> PNListEnq = new List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>();
            PNListEnq.Add(new HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "PN", FieldName = "Segment Tag", Value = "PN", Mandatory = "Y", CharacterType = "A/N", Position = 0, MaxLength = 04, FixedLength = "Y", CharToRead= ?  }); // replace ? with length of Value
```

Comment: Generic types can have constructors, and you can have custom property get/set logic by not using the automatic-property syntax.

Comment: do you want `public int CharToRead { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) ? 0 : base.Value.Length; } }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then in the consumer class you can just use Value.Length. But if you still want to use CharToRead this would be the solution:

```
public class HeaderTypeEnq<T> : HeaderType<T>
{
    public string Mandatory { get; set; }
    public string CharacterType { get; set; }
    public string FixedLength { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public int CharToRead
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return Value.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should check for null Value

Comment: Add null check and this will be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a really great way to do this based on what you've told us, but you can definitely have constructors on generic classes, so you could do something like this (with, of course, whatever parameters you want):

```
public class HeaderTypeEnq<T> : HeaderType<T>
{
    public HeaderTypeEnq(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.CharToRead = this.Value.Length;
    }

    public string Mandatory { get; set; }
    public string CharacterType { get; set; }
    public string FixedLength { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public int CharToRead { get; set; }    
}
```

Then you can use that,

```
PNListEnq.Add(new HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>("PN")
    {
        FieldTag = "PN",
        FieldName = "Segment Tag",
        Mandatory = "Y",
        CharacterType = "A/N",
        Position = 0,
        MaxLength = 04,
        FixedLength = "Y"
    });
```

Beyond that, assuming you want to be able to modify the property in question (which rules out a getter-only property with custom logic), the only other option I can think would be modify your property's setter logic, but this seems like it would get confusing very quickly.

```
private string _value;
public string Value
{
    get
    {
        return this._value;
    }
    set
    {
        this._value = value;
        this.CharToRead = value.Length;
    }
}
```

Of course, that would also involve modifying the base class (at the very least to make that property `virtual`), which may or may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am not even able to create a constructor since I have a generic
>   class."

That´s whrong, you CAN create instances of generic type and therefor also build a constructor:

```
public HeaderTypeEnq<T>(string value) {
    this.Value = value;
    this.CharToRead = this.Value.Length;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I am having to pass a parameter. I don't want to pass a parameter.